# Use inkjet cartridge to color filiment?

Tags: color

Is it possible to use a standard color inkjet cartridge to color filament for full color 3D printing?

It seems like a natural next step to me, but I haven't seen much of anything on this. (Just a few ancient experiments on reprap wiki.)

I've learned that some inkjet printers have the heads built into the cartridge whereas others it's part of the printer.  I think the former would be more appropriate.

Unfortunately I haven't seen anything on actually how to drive the cartridges.  I'm guessing the mfgr's treat this as a trade secret (?)  Still, there's got to be some overseas reverse-engineer... something... on this, right?

Anybody have resources/notes they'd like to share?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes a lot of sense - you don't need that kind of resolution, and getting a sufficient amount of ink that way to coat the filament would be hard. If you're going to be switching colors rapidly, you'd need a long purge between colors anyway. I also doubt the type of ink is suitable for sticking to filament materials.

If you really want an automated filament coloring system, I would do it with Sharpies and actuators to move individual ones on/off of the filament as it passes through. Coloring PLA with Sharpies prior to printing is a known-working technique, and there are even models available on Thingiverse for holders to keep them in place while the filament runs through. Designing the actuators to switch individual ones on/off, and the firmware controls for them, would be the natural next step.

Here are some examples I did with manual coloring of natural translucent PLA (from left to right: uncolored, silver Sharpie, and red Sharpie):

[image: 3 printed nuts, colored as described in text]

I didn't color a long enough segment of filament or properly purge for any of them, which is why the coloring is inconsistent/incomplete. But the technique definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

AS an FYI, this is becoming available commercially:
https://www.xyzprinting.com/en-US/product-level/PROFESSIONAL/color-series

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please [edit] your answer to explain why it is right. Additionally, we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. [*link only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) answers are frowned upon (as links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)) & will be rendered useless if the linked-to content disappears. If you add more context and detail from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.

Comment: I'd be skeptical of anything from this company. Speaking of inkjet they're the inkjet printer loss-leader scam of 3D printing. Printers that refuse to use filament other than their own overpriced ones, software lock-in, ... Also using illegitimate IP claims to takedown competitors' products from Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a thing since I think 2-3 years. There's such a printer from XYZ printing. It's not cheap but worth it. https://www.xyzprinting.com/en-US/product/da-vinci-color

The other thing thats available right now is a new print technology named Multy Jet Fusion, where drops of resin being colored and droped to a 3D Print: